# How to change multiple part of url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, browser

I want to change

https://www.ebay.com/usr/username?_trksid=p2047675.l2559

to

http://www.ebay.com/sch/username/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_ipg=&_from=

I manage to change `usr` to `sch` using this

```
if (currentURL.match("usr")) {
    location.href = location.href.replace("usr", "sch");
};
```

But how to change the other part

```
?_trksid=p2047675.l2559
```

to

```
/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_ipg=&_from=
```

(Note: "p2047675.l2559" this number different for every person and only "?_trksid=" are fixed)

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try out your code using the following .

```
var oldUrl = "https://www.ebay.com/usr/username?_trksid=p2047675.l2559";
var match = /\?/.exec(oldUrl);
console.log(match.index);
var  newUrl = oldUrl.substring(0 , match.index);
var newUrl = newUrl + "/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1&_ipg=&_from="
console.log(newUrl);
```

First we have find the index of `?` then we have substring url till `?` and then joind the new part of url .